# ajax sends second post request after success

Tags: ajax, jsp

I'm making an ajax post call on click of a button as below. But on success, the page is again submitted to the form-post url on the jsp page. I'm not sure why this is happening and how I can prevent the same.

**Ajax call:**

```
var urlsub = window.location.protocol + "//"+ window.location.host + contextPath+ "/saveEOI";
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url :  urlsub,
        cache : false,
        async: false,
        data: {'applicationId' : applicationId       
            },

        success : function(data) {  
            alert("success");
        },
        error : function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
```

The success alert is successfully shown, but after that another post request is generated for the jsp page form action...which causes a 405 error. I want to stop the execution after success.

```
<s:form action="expressEOI"  class="form-horizontal" name= "EOI" id="EOI"
        enctype="multipart/form-data"   modelAttribute="expressEOIBean">
```

Request if anybody can help me out..where I am going wrong.

Comment: When is your $.ajax executed ? On pressing submit-button ? If so the form gets submitted and you click-handler is executed at the same time ?

Comment: on ckick of button: $('#eoiSavebtn').attr('onClick','javascript:saveEOI("'+contextPath+'","'+loanApplicationDetails.applicationId+'")');

Comment: Please share the html-code of your button. It might be a submit-button of a form.

Comment: <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
     <div class="pull-right">
      <button class="btn btn-info" name="eoiSavebtn" id="eoiSavebtn">Please
       Save</button>
     </div>
    </div>